# Apache access only to hostname not ip

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

Does anyone know is it possible to setup apache vhost in a following way:

- if user access to www.example.com then vhost takes it to /www/example.com
- if user access to www.example2.com then vhost takes it to /www/example2.com
- if user access to an IP of server 1.2.3.4 then it gets some default page /www/default

Is it possible to make a generic configuration that will avoid having exact IP address of the server in it ? (so that if server IP changes it's not neccessary to change configuration files)

Comment: I recommend you to block all IP-based vhosts to avoid scanners. I block it with modsecurity rules from modsecurity_crs_21_protocol_anomalies.conf

Answer (score 0):

For your default page it would like this (this allows any IP address to go to the default page).  The * is a wildcard for the IP address.

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
```

For virtual hosts your config file would look like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot "/www/example1.com/"
        ServerName example1.com    
        ServerAlias www.example1.com
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot "/www/example2.com/"
        ServerName example1.com    
        ServerAlias www.example1.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: and where did you tell it to go to /www/default when an IP is entered as URL ?

Answer (score 0):

if you re using seperate config files for the virtual hosts, for example in the subdirectory /etc/apache2/vhosts.d/, then you can just create one config with a name starting with 0_ and then any name (0_default_host.conf) and use just any ServerName.
This config will be used for every request which is coming without proper hostname.

In this config file you can just create a redirect which is redirecting every request to nothing.
Something like that: RewriteRule .* - [F]

This setup will block every hostname and ipaddress which is not handeled by the other config files.